# Берци чи берці?

Tags: орфографія

У Вікіпедії:
Бе́рці (рос. берцы, скорочення від берцовые ботинки — «гомілкові черевики») — розмовна назва масивних військових черевиків на шнурівках із твердим передком.
Але:
 Такі моделі можна знайти у передових європейських виробників, які виготовляють тактичне взуття і БЕРЦИ для армії.

То як правильно? Чи можна використовувати обидва варіанти?

Comment: За офіційним правописом — «берці» («капці», «танці»). Див. також [«Чим зумовлено вживання флексії -и в родовому відмінку?»](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3049).

Comment: Будь ласка, завжди надавайте посилання на те, що стверджуєте. Наприклад, цілком імовірно, що друга фраза є наслідком банального одруку. Але ми про це ніколи не дізнаємося, якщо не матимемо посилань.

Comment: щоби дізнатися, як це робити, почитайте тред у цій кімнаті, будь ласка: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74141/room-for-p-vovk-and-mariia-matskevych

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Словник жарґонної лексики української мови](http://ukr-zhargon.wikidot.com/b) подає:

> БЕРЦІ  (-ів) мн.; військ. Військові чоботи з високими халявами. Балабін.

[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%86%D1%96_(%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F)), як ви зазначили, подає:

> Бе́рці (рос. берцы, скорочення від берцовые ботинки — «гомілкові
>   черевики») — розмовна назва масивних військових черевиків на шнурівках
>   із твердим передком.

Є навіть пісня з назвою ["берці"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0i9jfNkjucg).

З іншого боку, ґуґл дає 35 600 результатів на ["берці"](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%86%D1%96%22&source=lnt&tbs=lr:lang_1uk&lr=lang_uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOt9aS0-nZAhVIyqQKHfTUCFsQpwUIHw&biw=1366&bih=662) і 31 600 результатів на ["берци"](https://www.google.com.ua/search?lr=lang_uk&biw=1366&bih=662&tbs=lr%3Alang_1uk&ei=7fKnWr-0DYqUkwWGzJ3ICw&q=%22%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B8%22&oq=%22%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B8%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l7j0i10k1j0l2.9572.9572.0.9780.1.1.0.0.0.0.142.142.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.141....0.RBxOHTGV-VM), тобто, різниця невелика.

Офіційні словники поки що з цього приводу мовчать.

Робимо висновок, що слово ще не до кінця усталилося в нашій мові, але посилаючись на вікі, сленґ, деяку перевагу в результатах на ґуґлі і поширення першого варіанту в культурних колах можна до офіційного рішення (якщо воно колись буде) надати перевагу закінченню "і".

До того ж, як слушно у коментарі зауважив пан @Sasha, українській мові взагалі не властиві слова, що закінчуються на "ци", тож можна впевнено писати "берці".

Comment: Чи є в українській мові хоч одне слово на _-ци_ (у множині називного відмінку)?

Comment: @Sasha слушне питання. Зараз доповню відповідь.

Comment: Також можна послатися на правило дев'ятки: https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Правило_дев%27ятки

Comment: @Palindromer ну, не те щоб. Я там не бачу нічого про "и/і" наприкінці слова, також бачу там "Лейпциг", що вже зовсім російське, адже навіть болгари вже примудрилися якось написати "Лайпциг".

Comment: Так, ваша правда - не помітив.

Comment: Стосовно слів, що закінчуються на -ци, то є "палаци", "принци", "абзаци", "шприци", "піци", "форзаци", "герци" (величина). Проте в даних словах і не відчувається, що може бути інакше закінчення.

Comment: @Palindromer не буду вносити ваші коментарі до відповіді, бо не бачу розбіжності, а як доповнення хай залишається, прапорці ставити також не буду)